# Asymmetric relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I read that asymmetric relations are closed under intersection and set difference but not under complement.

Although I could understand why is it like that, but we can represent set difference as

A - B = A intersection B' .

Now it is closed under difference and intersection. So it should also be closed under complement according to the equation. Why is it not like that ?

Comment: Your reasoning shows that if something is closed under intersection and complement, so it is closed under difference, but not the other way around. It is not like you could resolve this equality for $B'$.

Comment: We know that set difference is closed . So for set difference to be closed on LHS, complement has to closed on RHS as intersection is also closed on RHS, right ?

Comment: Being closed under intersection or so is a property of a family of sets, *but* your left and right hand sides are no such families. You cannot argue that way.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that the term is *asymmetric*? Because asymmetric relations *are* closed under complement. Do you possibly meant *antisymmetric*?

Comment: How asymmetric relations are closed under complement ? Consider set {1,2,3} and relation R ={(1,2)}. Now R' contains {(2,3) , (3,2)} . So not asymmetric.

Comment: Closed under complement does not mean that any subset of the complement has this propery. The full complement would be $$\{1,2,3\}\times\{1,2,3\}-R=\{(1,1),(1,3),(3,1),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3)\}$$ which is asymmetric.

Comment: I know its not the complement. I just wrote the subset of the complement which would not follow the asymmetric property. In your case, (2,3), (3,2) is present and that doesn't make it asymmetric

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65907/discussion-between-m-winter-and-zephyr).

Answer (score 0):

Asymmetric relations are actually closed under complement. Let $R$ be an asymmetric relation, i.e. there exists a pair $(x,y)\in R$ with $(y,x)\not\in R$.

If $R'$ is the complement, then $(y,x)\in R$, but $(x,y)\not\in R$. Therefore $R'$ is also asymmetric.

Assuming my definitions of your terms are correct, this violates the statement of your question.